# Problems referencing model in function based view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

As the title states, I'm having trouble referencing my account model in my cmsUserDetailEdit view. The site itself doesn't break, but it seems like its just not able to find the model, as all the placed where the model is referenced is empty.

I've tried placing the account in the context. E.g: `'account': account`, but without luck.

## views.py

```
def cmsUserDetailEdit(request, pk):
    account = Account.objects.all()
    accounts = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=accounts.user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(request.POST, instance=accounts)

        if u_form.is_valid() and a_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            a_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account updated')
            return redirect('/cms/test/')
    else:
        u_form = UserEditPersonalForm(instance=accounts.user)
        a_form = AccountEditPersonalForm(instance=accounts)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'a_form': a_form,
    }    

    return render(request, 'cms/users/cms-users-user-edit.html', context)
```

## cms-users-user-edit.html

```
<div class="note-card-content">
    <div class="content">
        {{ account.note }} <!-- This part is empty -->
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't add accounts and account to the context dict. (Note, it's a bit strange to call the list of accounts "account" and the single account "accounts".)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, this resolved it :)